# WP Задать для вывода комментариев нужный формат даты

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при смене формата даты для вывода комментариев всем комментам начала присваиваться каждый день текущая дата, вместо даты публикации из базы
Вот мой код

```
// comment date
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wpse_comment_date_18350375' );
function wpse_comment_date_18350375( $date ) {
    $date = date("M j, Y");
    return $date;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста как поправить код? Не могу понять что не так задаю [по документации](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_comment_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция date без второго параметра выводит текущую дату.

Замените код функции одной строкой:

```
return date( 'M j, Y', strtotime( $date ) );
```

```
// comment date
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'wpse_comment_date_18350375' );
function wpse_comment_date_18350375( $date ) {
    return date( 'M j, Y', strtotime( $date ) );
}
```

Comment: Заменил / Почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: Что значит - не срабатывает? Взрывается монитор?

Comment: Только что вставил эти 4 строки на тестовый сайт - всё работает именно так, как и ожидалось, прдставление даты в комментариях изменилось.

Comment: Сорри, все хорошо/ Не так вызов делал/ Спасибо